# How to add a horizontal line in table by using pander or pandoc.table

Tags: r, knitr, pander

The header and content of a table generated by pander or pandoc.table is separated by a horizontal line. Is there a way to add a new horizontal line between a specific location in the content? For example:
 [image]
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK `pandoc`'s markdown does not support such markup for [tables](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables), so if you need such customization and you are OK with only one output format (eg LaTeX/pdf), then you should rather use `xtable` or other similar pkg.

Comment: @daroczig, thank you. I will try the xtable.